# 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm working on examples from book wrangling with Python.

Trying to read data from a CSV file into a dictReader object named header_rdr.

```
header_rdr = DictReader(open('/Users/tcssig/Downloads/data-wrangling-master/data/unicef/mn_headers.csv', 'r'))
```

When I try list comprehension to read all dict values in a list, using

```
header_rows = [h.decode('utf-32') for h in header_rdr]
```

Error message i get is: `'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'.`

How do I proceed without decoding the string before passing into a string.

Also, without decoding the elements, I got the error as :

UnicodeDecodeError: `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2807: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: `DictReader` yields an OrderedDict for each row of the CSV. But you should be opening the file with the correct encoding mode. You aren't using Python 2, are you?

Comment: I'm using python 3 and opening the file in default read text mode. What should I do ?

Comment: Pass the arg `encoding='utf-32'` in the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) call.

Answer (score 1):

On iteration, a `csv.DictReader` yields `dict`s - hence its name.
Each dict represents a CSV record in the style `{<column_header>: <column_value>}`.
To decode the file's contens as UTF-32, you can specify the encoding as argument of `open`.

```
header_rdr = DictReader(open(…, 'r', encoding='utf-32'))
```